# C# On_buttonClick, remove null contents from listbox

Tags: c#

How do I setup a button click to remove only null contents from a listbox and keep the listbox populated.

Example:

```
Work  
Files  
here  

Armor
```

Result (on_button_click,changes listbox):

```
Work  
Files  
here  
Armor
```

Any help always appricated.

Comment: What UI technology? WinForms? WPF? ASP.Net?

Comment: Based on his previous questions, he's probably using WinForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop backwards through the items in the ListBox and remove the items that you don't like.

For example:

```
for (int i = listBox.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(listBox.Items[i] as String))
        listBox.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

The loop needs to be backwards because otherwise, all of the upcoming indices will move down.

Comment: You'll need `i--` rather than `i++`

Comment: Fixed; thanks.  I'm too used to writing normal `for` loops and `List.RemoveAll`.

Comment: This could possibly also throw an error... "If you're mucking with the list at the same time as walking it, you're going to get errors either way. If adding items, then the for loop may skip some silently, while the foreach loop will throw. If removing items, then the for loop may throw an index out of range if you're unlucky, but will probably work most of the time."

Comment: @Roboto: As long as you're only removing items (and not adding any), there's nothing wrong with going backwards.

Comment: @SLaks: Check. I was more talking about multiple reader/writers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

Whoops, as noted, you cannot iterate through a collection and modify it at the same time. Therefore, I present some Frankenstein code:

```
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<String> removeMe = new List<String>();
    foreach(String x in listBox.Items)
    {
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
       {
           removeMe.Add(x);
       }
    }

    foreach(String x in removeMe)
    {
          listBox.Items.Remove(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work; you can't modify a collection inside its `foreach`.

Comment: Yep, SLaks is right.. just tried it myself.. code does not work.

Comment: "List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. An enumerator can only be used if the list does not change."

Comment: You guys are right, I forgot about that. Changed to some horrific, overcomplicated code. :)

Comment: @James: I was about to post that exact solution :)

Comment: It's not horrific, but it's needlessly inefficient.  It could be made much simpler using LINQ.  (`listBox.Items.OfType<String>().Where<String>(String.IsNullOrEmpty).ToArray()`)

Comment: (Although it would still be needlessly inefficient)

Comment: I imagine the CLR would optimize it though.